# Vim automatically saves unnamed register on quit. Why only 50 lines?

Tags: vim

Vim automatically saves the unnamed register (the one used by `y` and `p`) on quit and carries it over to the next session. This is great. But looks like it only saves the first 50 lines. Where is this configured?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "auto-save" is done by viminfo. `:h viminfo` to learn what it is.

Regarding the 50 lines quote for register, it was set by `viminfo` option. By default, it is

```
'100,<50,s10,h
```

You can set:

```
set viminfo='100,<999,s10,h
```

to have max. 999 lines for each register in viminfo.

If you just want to simply save all lines for registers, you just remove the `<xx` from viminfo option.

Comment: Thanks! `:h 'viminfo'` says the default is `'100,<50,s10,h`, and each parameter is identified by a starting character. Did you accidentally omit the `'` character from the first parameter? Or is it optional?

Comment: Plus it looks like `set viminfo` only works without the quotes. I'll edit the answer with these changes, hopefully not in error.

Comment: You removed the apostrophes (`'`). Why? `:h 'viminfo'` says _"The string should be a comma separated list of parameters, each consisting of a single character identifying the particular parameter, followed by a number or string which specifies the value of that parameter."_ `'` is one of the identifying characters.

Comment: @DanielDarabos oops, you are right, I thought it was your typo (the tick for the code block).  I will edit it right now.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, it does look like a typo :). `'` is a peculiar choice for an identifier when the letters had not even been exhausted yet.